# ASP.NET 5 MVC – How do I change the starting URL for an Intranet-hosted application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I require my Intranet-based project to start up in the following place with the URL: http://localhost:8082/CMWebApp

However when I run it in debug mode in Visual Studio 2015 via IIS Express or from within IIS itself it appears as: 
http://localhost:8082/

I then have to type the CMWebApp bit myself onto the end of the URL in the Browser. Not a complicated thing to do I wouldn’t have thought but I have not been able to configure the Project to do this. Can anyone advise how to do so please?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For asp.net-5 web project here it is:

Right click on the Project -> Properties -> Debug  then set the "Launch URL"
[image]

Comment: Works a treat thanks! What happens when I want to deploy it to IIS?

Comment: I haven't gotten a chance to use this, but you can try adding:  app.UseWelcomePage("/CMWebApp");     http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/diagnostics.html#the-welcome-page

Comment: Thanks, tried it but the URL still does not contain the CMWebApp at the end. I'm thinking the config needs to be added in IIS somewhere but I cannot see where?

Comment: Well, this is an MVC app right? If so, then configure your MVC routing to default to CMWebApp

Comment: Thanks Golois: I am new to ASP.NET and MVC and still learning the ropes: could you very kindly point me in the right direction on how to do this please? that would be awesome; thanks for your help so far, Jeremy

Comment: No, its the name I've given the Application. The controller is called CM_Web_ApplicationController

Answer (score 0):

On the server environment it is not a ASP.NET 5 issue, but more of a hosting environment change.  In IIS, you need to define the folder you are hosting your app as a Virtual Application under the root site and deploy to it using the deployment tool of your choice, MSDeploy I presume.